# Segmentation fault - Magical Record

Tags: objective-c, segmentation-fault, magicalrecord

I keep getting Segmentation fault's from my users inside of MagicalRecord's code:

```
-[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord_DataImport) MR_addObject:forRelationship:] in NSManagedObject+MagicalDataImport.m on Line 144
```

I'm not sure how to replicate or fix the issue in my code though. This is what I'm doing:

```
- (void)saveResources:(NSArray*)resources {
    NSDictionary *attr = resources[0];

    // needs to update the id of _this_ object
    [self.item importValuesForKeysWithObject:attr];
    [[self.item managedObjectContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
}
```

It is the `importValuesForKeysWithObject` method that is causing issues. This method is being called after a download completes (`AFJSONRequestOperation`).

Whenever I test this locally I have no issue with it and it only happens every once in awhile for my users. So how can I figure out what is causing the segmentation fault and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My  guess is that your variable attr contains nil elements, which causes the segfaults when `importValuesForKeysWithObject` is processing it. I would do some testing on attr first before passing it on.

Comment: I can see null values go into it and not crash. Is there any reason why it would only do it sometimes / how I can replicate it? I print the dictionary before passing it to `importValuesForKeysWithObject` and I see "<null>" for some values.

Comment: I don't know if or how `importValuesForKeysWithObject` handles null values, but they could be a potential cause for segfaults. An easy test would be to remove all the null values from your dictionary before passing it to `importValuesForKeysWithObject`, and see if you still get the segfaults.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured I should do. I'll be pushing out a TestFlight again today so I'll see if any more come in this week. If I don't get anymore I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thanks.